# Downloadable Super Output Areas

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I was planning on drawing some deprivation maps this afternoon, but I can't find a site to download the Lower Super Output Area boundaries from to display the data. The only link I can find is to a [word document that allows me to order some CDs](http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/Info.do;jessionid=ac1f930b30d69fa4c598cc9340cb9289a061517e4451?m=0&s=1254929199734&enc=1&page=aboutneighbourhood/geography/superoutputareas/soaboundaries/soa-boundaries.htm&nsjs=true&nsck=true&nssvg=false&nswid=1280) but I can't beleive that is the only way to get the data.

Please someone tell me that ONS haven't regressed that badly while I was away.

Comment: By Email - http://www.ons.gov.uk/about-statistics/geography/products/boundaries/index.html

Comment: But they are still going to mail me CDs :-(

Comment: I guess they don't have an FTP server - and more cutbacks prevent them from getting one. CD was the way it was 5 years ago but moving forward to direct downloads is a bit too far.

Comment: I'm sure I could download ward boundaries for 2001 - may be because I was an academic in those days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through this process just last week (email, then CD in the post). Couldn't believe it either - although they posted (for free, anywhere worldwide I think) within hours of my email and I got them a couple of days later. Not sure how this can save costs over a download link..

I'd put them online myself but guess there must be licensing issues.

Seems very old-school, especially when all the census statistics are available through a web REST API, and the OS serve out live vector data for other UK boundaries.